# Try to create a table from Select - SqL Server 2008 throws error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, create-table

Hi I am trying to create a table using inner select statement...

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE JmxMonSer AS (SELECT * FROM services WHERE monitoring_enabled = 1);
```

But keep getting error:

> *Incorrect Syntax near keyword 'AS', Severity 15*

please advice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT * into JmxMonSer FROM services WHERE monitoring_enabled=1
```

If the table already exists (and the columns types and ordering line up), you can use:

```
INSERT INTO JmxMonSer SELECT * FROM services WHERE monitoring_enabled=1
```

Comment: awesome, that worked, so I guess sql server has got a different syntax, when compared to the sql*. Many thanks

Answer (score 13):

I'm almost positive that SQL Server doesn't have a `CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT...` syntax, but you can use `SELECT INTO`:

```
SELECT * 
INTO JmxMonSer
FROM services 
WHERE monitoring_enabled=1
```

Check the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for proper uses of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The below syntax is for using sub-query instead of using static table name...
because sometime the required result set is coming from different queries..

```
SELECT * 
INTO JmxMonSer
From (SELECT * FROM services WHERE monitoring_enabled = 1) as X
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SELECT INTO`:

```
SELECT *
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM table1;
```

src: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp