# How do I convert/save the query results in into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please can you help me out. I need to save the results of this inner join query into a table.

```
select *
from [dbo].[List of 7671 Zim Acquittals Used By EY] inner join
     [dbo].[Zim Phase 3 - Combo of Phases 1 - 3 _ 6 Aug For SQL Master]
     on [dbo].[List of 7671 Zim Acquittals Used By EY].[Ref1]=[dbo].[Zim Phase 3 - Combo of Phases 1 - 3 _ 6 Aug For SQL Master].[Ref1]
```

Thanks Chris

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: I really recommend reconsidering your name choices for your objects here. Also, I strongly suggest using aliases and not using 3 part naming for your columns. The latter is [due to be deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) in SQL Server, and the former will make your code a lot more succinct (especially with *those* object names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
select *
into [dbo].[NewTable]
from [dbo].[List of 7671 Zim Acquittals Used By EY] inner join
[dbo].[Zim Phase 3 - Combo of Phases 1 - 3 _ 6 Aug For SQL Master]
on [dbo].[List of 7671 Zim Acquittals Used By EY].[Ref1]=[dbo].[Zim Phase 3 - Combo of Phases 1 - 3 _ 6 Aug For SQL Master].[Ref1]
```

Comment: You're welcome, you can click the up arrow button to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SELECT INTO statement`.`SELECT INTO statement` copies data from one table into a new table.

The following SQL statement copies data from more than one table into a new table:

```
select *
into [dbo].[Table_name]
from [dbo].[List of 7671 Zim Acquittals Used By EY] inner join [dbo].[Zim Phase 3 - Combo of Phases 1 - 3 _ 6 Aug For SQL Master] on [dbo].[List of 7671 Zim Acquittals Used By EY].[Ref1]=[dbo].[Zim Phase 3 - Combo of Phases 1 - 3 _ 6 Aug For SQL Master].[Ref1]
```

Or you can use another variant: `INSERT INTO Statement.`
The INSERT INTO SELECT statement copies data from one table and inserts it into another table.

`INSERT INTO SELECT` requires that data types in source and target tables match.
But at first you need to create table, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Name(
    Field1 <type>, 
    Field2<type>,
    Field3 <type>
)
```

After that, you can use following query:

```
  INSERT INTO Table_name (Field1,Field2, Field3) 
  SELECT * from [dbo].[List of 7671 Zim Acquittals Used By EY] inner join [dbo].[Zim Phase 3 - Combo of Phases 1 - 3 _ 6 Aug For SQL Master on [dbo].[List of 7671 Zim Acquittals Used By EY].[Ref1]=[dbo].[Zim Phase 3 - Combo of 1 - 3 _ 6 Aug For SQL Master].[Ref1]
```

Answer (score 0):

To Insert into Temp table, use below query

```sql
select * into #temp from  (Your Query)
```

To Insert into Physical table , create table with required Columns:

```sql
INSERT INTO Tablename
SELECT Columnnames FROM TABLE NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use CTAS i.e. if only table structure needs to be copied

```
Create table as select * from tablename
where 1 = 2;
```

In SQL server CTAS is not available so you have to use

```
SELECT * INTO NEW_TABLE FROM EXISTING_TABLE WHERE 1 = 2;
```

You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940477/try-to-create-a-table-from-select-sql-server-2008-throws-error)